# How to export Java eclipse Plugin Project to a executable jar file?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I am developing an eclipse application as a plugin project. I am able to export it as .product file and I am able to run it outside eclipse. Now, I have a requirement to schedule tasks in my plugin project. So, I have to make my project as JAR file and use that in scheduling. Since Plugin projects do not contain any Main methods, how to convert it to a Runnable JAR File?

Comment: You can't do this. Eclipse plugins will only run in a complete Eclipse RCP.

Comment: Is there any other way to schedule tasks in a plugin project ?

Comment: You can use various timer services such as `ScheduledExecutorService` in the RCP while it is running.

Comment: Will this be executed even if the product is not running ?

Comment: No, I said 'while the RCP is running'. If you want to run something at other times you can write a 'headless RCP' and run it periodically using something like 'cron'

Answer (score -1):

I believe you would need main method to make it as runnable java project, please find the instructions below link

https://support.smartbear.com/alertsite/docs/monitors/web/selenium/export-eclipse-java-project-as-runnable-jar.html

Comment: That link isn't about exporting Eclipse plugins